# Чи були випадки зміни іноземних топонімів на більш близькі до іншомовного оригіналу?

Tags: переклад, власні-назви, запозичені-слова, історія-мови, фонетика

[Стаття](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China) у вікіпедії про Китайську Народну Республіку говорить:

> The official name of the modern state is the "People's Republic of China" (Chinese: 中华人民共和国; pinyin: Zhōnghuá Rénmín Gònghéguó). The shorter form is "China" Zhōngguó (中国), from zhōng ("central" or "middle") and guó ("state, nation-state"), a term which developed under the Zhou Dynasty in reference to its royal demesne.

З цього випливає, що китайською самоназвою є `Zhōngguó`. Аудіоприклад вимови можна знайти за цим [посиланням](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Zh-Zhonghua_renmin_gongheguo.ogg) в якому `Zhōnghuá`(більш поширений варіант `Zhōngguó`) я розпізнаю як `Джьонгуа`.

Тож у зв'язку з цим маю два питання:

1. *риторичне: Чи варто вживати самоназву "Джьонгуа" замість усталеної назви "Китай"?*
2. *вимагає відповіді:* **Чи існують у історії української мови випадки, коли усталена іноземна географічна назва замінювалася на більш відповідну до того варіанту який вживають тамтешні мешканці?**

Comment: Додамо до питання Грузію (Сакартвело) і Фінляндію (Суомі). Думаю, не треба, якщо для китайців, фіннів і грузинів ці назви не є образливими.

Comment: На аудіо вимовляють 中华 «Zhōnghuá», а не 中国 «Zhōngguó», ці два слова рівнозначні, та останнє вживається частіше в значенні «Китай». Перше вживається в основному в назві КНР.

Comment: На мою думку одним з прикладів є заміна назви "Білорусія" на "Біларусь"

Comment: чи `Білорусія` колись було усталеною назвою в українській мові? я вважаю що ні, хіба що у суржику

Comment: @P.Vovk - Схоже, що для Грузії така назва все ж видається непідходящою, у 2011 році Міністерство закордонних справ Грузії [висловило прохання](http://www.rbc.ru/politics/27/06/2011/5703e8f39a79477633d34a78) до всіх країн світу називати їхню державу — Джорджією (Georgia), на англійський манер.

Comment: @YellowSky >Думаю, не треба, якщо для китайців, фіннів і грузинів ці назви не є образливими.
Будь ласка, не поширюйте тут посилання на російські медіа: 
а) їх не всі розуміють.
б) вони занадто часто брешуть.

Comment: До речі, а чи не спробувати примінити правило до Швейцарії?

Comment: Додам що Німеччина англійською Germany, французькою Allemagne, іспанською Alemania, німецькою Deutchland і вони не переймаються.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Є кілька країн (у широкому значенні цього слова), які протягом ХХ століття в українській мові принаймні офіційно змінили назву на таку, яка ближча до тамтешньої мови й тамтешнього найменування країни, наприклад:

> Персія > Іран
>
> Киргизія > Киргизстан
>
> Башкірія > Башкортостан
>
> Татарська республіка > Татарстан
>
> Марійська республіка > Марі-Ел
>
> Якутія > Саха
>
> Берег Слонової Кістки > Кот-д’Івуар
>
> Острова Зеленого Мису > Кабо Верде
>
> Бірма > М’янма

**UPD:** З 1975 по 1989 Камбоджа звалася «Кампучія», що було близьким до місцевої назви країни державною кхмерською мовою, та потім державу було знову перейменовано на Королівство Камбоджа.

Comment: @SassaNF - А що не так? В Кот-д’Івуарі офіційна мова французька. А Кабо Верде вас не зацікавило? Бо це ж португальський вираз, португальська – офіційна мова Кабо Верде.

Comment: Так у тому й штука, що "офіційна мова", а не "тамтешня". В Індії ціла купа "тамтешніх" мов, і декілька офіційних. В Кот-д'Івуарі теж мешкає ціла купа племен зі своїми мовами - до того ж, їх географія відрізняється від Європейського поділу континенту. Ба навіть в Швейцарії 5 офіційних мов і 5 офіційних назв країни. А запозичують одну. За якою ознакою? Тут, думаю, ознак більше однієї.

Comment: @SassaNF - В Україні теж багато мов, та офіційна одна, і що з того? В Кот-д’Івуарі не менш як 78 тамтешніх мов, та при населенні в 24 млн найбільшою мовою, бауле, говорить не більше 2–3 млн людей, не думаю, що там нею друкують книжки, Біблію переклали на бауле лише в 1998 році. Французькою ж там навчають у школах і вона є там лінгва франка, там усі її знають, тому ваш протест відхилено. І до вашого відома, в Швейцарії 4, а не 5 офіційних мов, а в Індії 2 – гінді й англійська, при цьому десь половина населення, а це не менше 600 млн душ, не знають жодної з них – ці ваші приклади тут ні до чого.

Answer (score 4):

На додаток до відповіді Yellow Sky, на думку ще спадає **Мумбаї** та **Ченнаї**, що називались **Бомбей** та **Мадрас** до 1995 року, але зі зміною назв міст Індією, в українській мові ці назви також змінилися.

Comment: Оскільки це запитання має bounty (додатковий бонус), варто робити відповіді таким чином, щоб вони відповідали меті того, хто запропонував цей бонус. Мета сформульована так: *«У відповіді я б хотів побачити аналіз такого явища взагалом: що спільного є між відомими випадками? де є межа після якої подібні зміни стають неможливими?»*. Коли стікає термін bounty, робот підраховує кількість голосів і пропонує ту відповідь (надану **під час дії** bounty), яка отримала найбільше голосів. А оскільки ваша відповідь не відповідає цій вимозі, **я мушу її мінуснути**.

Comment: @bytebuster Питання було сформульоване так: *Тож у зв'язку з цим маю два питання: 1. риторичне: Чи варто вживати самоназву "Джьонгуа" замість усталеної назви "Китай"? 2. вимагає відповіді: Чи існують у історії української мови випадки, коли усталена іноземна географічна назва замінювалася на більш відповідну до того варіанту який вживають тамтешні мешканці?*
Я відповіла на друге запитання, те саме що вимагало відповіді, добавив нові випадки, що ще не були тут згадані. Але, будь ласка, якщо ви змушені, то мінусуйте.

Comment: Індійці ще Калькутту змінили на Колкату - https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0.